# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, scala, java-8, unsupported-class-version

Getting following error in runtime of the oozie job,we migrated java jdk 1.8 from 1.7 and compile was successful.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at com.twitter.scalding.RichXHandler$.<init>(XHandler.scala:38)
        at com.twitter.scalding.RichXHandler$.<clinit>(XHandler.scala)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool$.main(Tool.scala:152)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.main(Tool.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:56)
```

Comment: you are running scala version Y that was compile with a scala version X.

Comment: while running we are using spark,so can you tell us how do I know the version of scala say a specific version of spark be using.

Comment: "I can tell you* ? That sounds absurd.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I used 2.11 while my cluster was using Scala 2.10.  You have to use the same scala version as the environment/cluster you are running. If you run the spark-shell you can see which scala version is used.

```
> spark-shell
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.3
      /_/

Using Scala version **2.10.5** (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40)
```